# How does minlength attribute affects angular's event loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was writing a simple program to understand the basics of $watch and angular's event loop . Following is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <title>$watch</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div>
        <form name="myForm">
            <label>
            Enter a Name:   
            </label>
            <input type="text" ng-model="name" name="myName" required minlength="5" />
        </form>
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);
    app.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$log){
        $scope.name = "";
        $scope.$watch('name',function(newValue,oldValue){
            console.log('Value Changed');
            console.log("Old Value : " + oldValue);
            console.log("New Value : " + newValue);
        }); 
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

After running the program and observing the logs in console it shows different value when the minlength attribute is there in the input tag , and some other value after it is removed ,  but i am unable to make it out why so ?